# Given an increasing function $f$, to find a continuous function satisfying properties of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be an increasing function satisfying
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\infty.$$

Can we find a continuous increasing function $F$ on $[0,\infty)$ satisfying
$$\int_0^\infty F(x)\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\infty$$
and $F(x)\leq f(x)?$

Comment: You allow $g$ to be constantly zero? In that case, the second condition is vacuous.

Comment: I edited the question to make it less ambiguous. The function $g$ is not in my hand but have to be same for both $f,F.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since $f$ is increasing, it is almost everywhere continuous and in particular locally integrable. So we can define $F$ by $F(t)=0$ for $t<1$ and $F(t)=\int_{t-1}^tf(x)dx$ for $t\geq1$. This function will be continuous and increasing and satisfies $f(x-1)\leq F(x)\leq f(x)$. From the first inequality you can shown that the integral $\int_0^\infty F(x)\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ diverges.

Comment: Thanks. I also get the idea graphically.

Comment: From 1st property of $f$, clearly it is not integrable. Although it is locally integrable and that is what we require to define $F$. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah that's right will edit.